# What is the difference between a surface and the graph of a function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

When I was studying a book, Elementary classical analysis (Jerrold.E.Marsden), there was a confusing sentence.

"The unit sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ in $\mathbb R^3$ is a surface of the form $F(x,y,z)=c$ which is not the graph of a function." 
What does this sentence mean?

Is there any relevance between above sentence and following problems?

1). find the tangent plane to the graph of $z=x^2 + y^2$ at $(0,0)$

2). Find the equation of the tangent plane to the surface $x^2 - y^2 + xyz = 1$ at $(1,0,1)$

I think I have some confusion between a surface and a graph. right?

please help me~

Comment: The "graph of a function" is presumably the surface comprised of points $(x,y,z)$ which satisfy a relation $z=f(x,y)$. Such a surface will pass a "vertical line test," so no two points on the surface will lie on a given vertical line. However the sphere fails this vertical line test so it is not the graph of the function, though one can graph the upper or lower hemispheres individually.

Comment: I removed the graph-theory tag. Graph theory is something completely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ has *two* solutions for every $(x,y)$ satisfying $x^2 + y^2 < 1$. This means that we can't find a function $f$, such that the sphere is the graph $z = f(x,y)$. (A function has only *one* value for every choice of variables.)

A similar argument shows that the sphere is not the graph of a function of any other pair of the variables either.

This is similar to the one-variable setting: the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is not the graph of a function of $x$ or a function of $y$. Go through this simpler example first.